# Sort array connected to other array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have to array 1 for age label and 1 for age count. I wanted to sort the label how to make to values array sorted connected to the first one

```
AgeLabel = ['43 yo', '12 yo', '33 yo', '25 yo']
AgeCount = [ 10, 20 ,30 ,40 ]
```

expected result

```
AgeLabel = ['12 yo', '25 yo', '33 yo', '43 yo']
AgeCount = [ 20, 40 ,30 ,10 ]
```

Comment: Why don't you try an object array?. like  const age = [{label:'43 Y0', count:10}, {label:'12 yo', count:20}, ......]

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far, your best attempt (code). Please read [ask] and take the [tour]!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [array_multisort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) function is ideally suited for such tasks. Delivers exactly the expected result.

```
$AgeLabel = ['43 yo', '12 yo', '33 yo', '25 yo'];
$AgeCount = [ 10, 20 ,30 ,40];

array_multisort($AgeLabel,SORT_ASC,$AgeCount);
```

Answer (score 3):

Many options. For example:

```
asort($AgeLabel);

$AgeCount = array_map(function ($index) use ($AgeCount) {
    return $AgeCount[$index];
}, array_keys($AgeLabel));

$AgeLabel = array_values($AgeLabel); // only if you need ordered keys
```

or

```
$combined = array_combine($AgeLabel, $AgeCount);
ksort($combined);
$AgeLabel = array_keys($combined);
$AgeCount = array_values($combined);
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty, but i think you get idea.
First, merge both arrays, then order by value, and then split them.

```
$AgeLabel = ['43 yo', '12 yo', '33 yo', '25 yo'];
$AgeCount = [10, 20, 30, 40];
    
    
$AgeTmp = [];

foreach ($AgeLabel as $k => $v) {
    $AgeTmp[$AgeCount[$k]] = $AgeLabel[$k];
}

asort($AgeTmp);
$AgeLabel = [];
$AgeCount = [];

foreach ($AgeTmp as $k => $v) {
    $AgeLabel[] = $k;
    $AgeCount[] = $v;
}
```

Comment: For the last part (separating keys and values again) you can use [`array_keys`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [`array_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php), so you don't have to iterate over each one. Those are built-in PHP functions.

Comment: correct, stas.yaranovs answer has this and array_combined() and is quicker, so i dont update my answer...but thanks for the hint :)

Comment: This solution gives incorrect results if $ AgeCount contains the same values how [10,10,20 ..]